# Protege reverse object properties

Tags: artificial-intelligence, owl, ontology, protege, protege4

I am trying to define two reverse object properties.

The object properties are :

- `hasChild`
- `hasParent`

As it's obvious if `JOHN hasParent ANNA`, then `ANNA hasChild JOHN`.
This seems to be accomplished by using Protege's `InverseOf` but then if we assume `ANNA is Happy`,
The below DL Query:

```
hasChild only Happy
```

returns `JOHN` too. The reasoner explains that `hasChild is inverseOf hasParent`.
Can someone help me clear things up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on your description only, this does not look right. Can you give the details of what's in your ontology?

Comment: I'm wondering why there should be returning anything at all given the Open World Assumption. I tried to reproduce it with the given axioms, nothing has been returned in the DL Query tab. There must be other axioms in your ontology we don't know...

Answer (score 1):

`hasChild only Happy` is a universal restriction without accompanying existential restriction. Under Open World assumption, these universal restrictions end up including all individuals defined, because `for all` includes the cases where there is no filler for the property.

To verify if this is the case, create a named classe defined as `hasChild only Happy` and check which classes are equivalent to it. Most likely, you'll find `owl:Thing` in the results. therefore, all individuals will be answers to that query.

To avoid this, add `hasChild some Happy` to your query, so that there must be a filler before the inference can be drawn.

However, notice that you want the parent to be happy. Maybe you meant to reverse the direction and say `hasParent only Happy`?